# Installing ROS Indigo by source catkin building error

Tags: catkin, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I´m following this tutorial to install ROS Indigo by Source on Ubuntu 14.04: http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source

Everything worked until that point: 2.1.3 Building the catkin Workspace

Using this command to build catkin Workspace:
`$ ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

occurs in the following error message:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'catkin'
==> cmake /home/ROSproject/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/ROSproject/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ROSproject/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G Unix Makefiles in '/home/ROSproject/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin'

Unhandled exception of type 'OSError':

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 919, in build_workspace_isolated number=index + 1, of=len(ordered_packages)

File "src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 655, in build_package destdir=destdir, use_ninja=use_ninja

File "src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 390, in build_catkin_package run_command_colorized(cmake_cmd, build_dir, quiet, add_env=add_env)

File "src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 181, in run_command_colorized run_command(cmd, cwd, quiet=quiet, colorize=True, add_env=add_env)

File "src/catkin/bin/../python/catkin/builder.py", line 199, in run_command raise OSError("Failed command '%s': %s" % (cmd, e))
    
OSError: Failed command '['cmake', '/home/ROSproject/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/ROSproject/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ROSproject/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

<== Failed to process package 'catkin':
Failed command '['cmake', '/home/ROSproject/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/ROSproject/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ROSproject/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Command failed, exiting.
```

Thanks for help in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202768/installing-ros-indigo-by-source-catkin-building-error/) by [NRW_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/21591/nrw_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-02-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Judging from the error, it looks like you may not have `cmake` installed? Did you successfully run the `rosdep install ...` step in the tutorial?

A work around will be to install `cmake`, and since you're on Ubuntu you can just do `sudo apt-get install cmake`, but if `cmake` was not installed, then it is likely other things which need to be installed are not.

Also, if you were not aware, there are binary packages for Indigo on 14.04 on i386 and amd64, so unless you have a specific reason for compiling from source, you can just `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-...` for your packages.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-02-10**:
On behalf of @NRW_ROS: You were right. There were some deps missing from rosdep install ... . I forced the installation and it works now. Thanks a lot!